# How to build and run Flowdroid and use it to generate static function call graph?

Tags: android, call-graph, soot

I wish to generate a **static function call graph** for **API calls** in an **android application** after its decompilation using **APK tool**. I searched for ways for doing the same and I found **Flowdroid**.

I downloaded github projects for **Jasmin, Heros, Soot, soot-infoflow, soot-infoflow-android** from the link "https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow-android/wiki" .

I also downloaded the following:

- **Soot bundle (also contains Heros and Jasmin)**: [https://soot-build.cs.uni-paderborn.de/nightly/soot/sootclasses-trunk-jar-with-dependencies.jar](http://Android%20XML%20parser%20library:%20https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow-android/raw/develop/lib/axml-2.0.jar)
- **soot-infoflow**: https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow/releases/download/FlowDroid_2.0/soot-infoflow.jar
- **soot-infoflow-android**: https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow-android/releases/download/FlowDroid_2.0/soot-infoflow-android.jar
- **Libraries for Logging**: https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow-android/raw/develop/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar AND https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow-android/raw/develop/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
- **Android XML parser library**: https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow-android/raw/develop/lib/axml-2.0.jar

Please guide me on how to build them or proceed from here. Also the links for libraries for logging seem to be unavailable. Please help me with them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned the links for libraries and loggings are unavailable, the following might be useful
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadslf4jsimple175jar.htm

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadslf4japi175jar.htm